# Add a snowcap to a mountain

Tags: texturing, edit-mode, transforms

I made a mountain using the ANT addon. I gave texture to the mountain. Now I want to add a snowcap to it. Here is what I am thinking:

- Go to Edit mode, select patches and assign a vertex group. Then assign snow material to i.

- I am not sure how to select random size patches on the mountain.
- Sometimes Blender hangs in edit mode if I opt for higher subdivisions, like 300
- Also should I work on a 2 m x 2 m dimension mountain first and then after all modifications scale it to be 2 km x 2 km? What is the workflow?

The other option might be to find a snow object and use some scale/deform and put it on mountain.

Or duplicate the mountain, give it a snow texture, scale it slightly, and intersect with the original mountain.

[image]

Comment: hello can't you do it in the Shader Editor (paint a b&w mask that you use as factor in a Mix Shader between the mountain material and the snow material)?

Comment: Generated texture coordinates -> separate xyz -> take z into color ramp.  Same thing could be done for timberline

Comment: @moonboots I am a newbie, could you elaborate your solution/idea?

Comment: @AllenSimpson  I am a newbie, could you elaborate your solution/idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unwrap your object, in the *Shader Editor* create a *Texture > Image Texture*, plug it directly into the *Output*, in the *3D Scene* in *Solid* mode switch to *Texture Paint* mode and begin to paint white where you want to see the snow:

[image]

Then switch to *Rendered* preview, use the image you've painted as a factor between your basic mountain material and your snow material, through a *Shader > Mix Shader*, here I've used 2 *Principled BSDF* but of course your materials can be more complicated:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Real Snow](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/object/real_snow.html?utm_source=blender-3.6.1). It's an addon that, as far as I know, comes bundled with Blender. To enable it, go to *Preferences* -> *Addons* and look for *Object: Real Snow* and enable it, by clicking the checkbox.

[image: Enable Real Snow addon]

To apply snow to an object, select the object, and hit N to show the sidebar, if it is not already visible. If you enabled the addon, a tab named *Real Snow* should be there.
The *Coverage* controls the coverage, and if you set it lower than 100%, you will see holes in the snowcap.
The *Height* controls the thickness of the snow.
*Selected faces* controls whether all or only selected faces should receive snow.

It adds a layer of snow to all upward facing faces, or to selected faces only. It gives the layer a default snow material.

[image: Real Snow setup]

Here is a quick render, using very simple lighting (just a *Sky Texture*), and a very simplistic material for the mountain (a *Principled BSDF* with all but the color left at defaults), and a bblack background.

[image: Real Snow simplistic render]